# Make a basic running sprite effect

Tags: c#, xna, sprite

I'm building my very first game with *XNA* and i'm trying to get my sprite to run.
Everything is working fine for the first sprite.
E.g : if I go right(D) my sprite is looking right , if I go left(A) my sprite is looking left and if I don't touch anything my sprite is the default one.
Now what I want to do is if the sprite goes Right, i want to alternatively change sprites (left leg, right leg, left leg etc..) *xCurrent* is the current sprite drawn *xRunRight* is the first running Sprite and *xRunRight1* is the one that have to exchange with *xRunRight* while running right.
This is what I have now :

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float timer = 0f;
        float interval = 50f;
        bool frame1 = false ;
        bool frame2 = false;
        bool running = false;

        KeyboardState FaKeyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();


            if ((FaKeyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.A)) || (FaKeyboard.IsKeyUp(Keys.D)))
            {
                xCurrent = xDefault;
            }

            if (FaKeyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
            {

                timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
                if (timer > interval)
                {
                    if (frame1)
                    {
                        xCurrent = xRunRight;
                        frame1 = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        xCurrent = xRunRight1;
                        frame1 = true;

                    }
                }

                xPosition += xDeplacement;


            }
```

Any ideas...? I've been stuck on this for a while..
Thanks in advance and let me know if you need any other part from the code.

Comment: I know the frame 1, frame 2 and (timer > interval) logic is not working but it's where I was going before realizing that it wasn't going to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to reset the timer, you could do this when you hit the `timer interval` condition. Also, 50ms seems a bit too small for an interval, maybe you could do like 400ms?

Other than that, looks good, it will do what you want.

Alternatively, you could look into making **animated sprites** for walking. What you do is make an image with the walking animation sprites one next to the other, of the same size. You draw only a portion of this image (one sprite) and move through them based on time.

Here is a quick code for what could be an animated texture:

```
class AnimatedTexture2D : Texture2D
{
    int _numberOfImages;
    int _currentImage = 0;

    int _timeInterval;
    int _spriteWidth;

    public Rectangle DrawFromRectangle
    {
        get
        {
            return new Rectangle(_currentImage * _spriteWidth, 0, _spriteWidth, this.Height);
        }
    }

    public AnimatedTexture2D(Texture2D entireImage, int spriteWidth, int numberOfImages, int timeInterval)
        : base(entireImage.GraphicsDevice, entireImage.Width, entireImage.Height)
    {
        _numberOfImages = numberOfImages;
        _timeInterval = timeInterval;
        _spriteWidth = spriteWidth;

        Color[] data = new Color[entireImage.Width * entireImage.Height];
        entireImage.GetData<Color>(0, new Rectangle(0, 0, entireImage.Width, entireImage.Height), data, 0, entireImage.Width * entireImage.Height);

        this.SetData<Color>(data);
    }

    public void Animate(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        int totalImageTime = _timeInterval * _numberOfImages;
        int currentPoint = (int)gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds % totalImageTime;

        _currentImage = currentPoint / _timeInterval;
    }
}
```

Usage is fairly simple:

1) declare it somewhere:

```
AnimatedTexture2D animatedTexture;
```

2) initiate it with your texture (i had a 2560x64 sequence of 40 64*64 images), where individual images are placed next to each other horizontally:

```
animatedTexture = new AnimatedTexture2D(Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures\Loading"), 64, 40, 20);
```

3) in your Update() method, call:

```
animatedTexture.Animate(gameTime);
```

4) in your Draw() method, call:

```
SpriteBatch.Draw(animatedTexture, new Rectangle(20, 20, 64, 64), animatedTexture.DrawFromRectangle, Color.White);
```

Don't forget the DrawFromRectangle in part 4! (notice that the destination rectangle uses the declared individual part width, not the entire texture width which is in my test 2560 pixels)

Now, in your code you could forget the interval part, and the gametime part, and you could just use this instead of the default one!

Also, if you don't like my timing code (its ultra simple but lacks a way to reset the animation) change it so you have an elapsed time variable, and add to it like you do in your own code, and use that to change _currentImage. You could even make that variable public so you can use it to reset the animation (or set it to a specified point).

Of course, you could also make the default one an animated texture with only one frame so you can use the same code everywhere. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the last time Update(..) was called, and the interval should be... well.. an interval, that is, the difference between ElapsedGameTime and last call to update ElapsedGameTime.
Do it with a new member of your class (LastElapsedGameTimeUpdateCalled) or a static member of your sub.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that every animation is going to have the same number of frames you could keep 3 variables per sprite (encapsulate in class for best results).
BaseFrame is an integer to hold a global animation number.
SubFrame is an offset in to the animation that holds which frame you are currently on.
FrameAccumulator to hold timing information.

Each time update is called, add the number of ms since the last update to the accumulator.  Once the accumulator goes above your animation timing, increment SubFrame, and reset the accumulator.  Check to see if subFrame is greater than the number of frames for each animation, and if it is, set it back to 0.  You can get the real frame index from this by adding BaseFrame + Subframe.  When you need to display a different animation just change the BaseFrame.

Lets say that each animation has 3 frames, and you have 2 total animations.  You would have 6 total frames.  RunLeft would be BaseFrame 0, and RunRight would be BaseFrame 3.  That should easily give you the frame number to draw.